# LDAP vs local authentication?

Tags: authentication, ldap

I have many servers over 50. earlier we were using that LDAP authentication. Now we have decided to go to same username needs to be authenticate locally on server rather than LDAP authentication. something has messed up and we loose track there we have change the authentication scheme. 
Now I need to manually log in to all server and check. 
What is the fool proof way to check whether user account is authenticated locally or through LDAP ? 
PS: I have tried checking /etc/passwd file for user name but it's not working. though entry is there, user account is authenticated through LDAP :(

Comment: I am not sure. Do you want to list all ldap users?

Comment: Nope, I just want my Linux server which is running RHEL not to authenticate alix from the LDAP server but from /etc/passwd file. Hope this make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
getent passwd "username"
```

Copy the result into the buffer

```
vipw
```

Paste the line into it. Either at the end or at the right place.

```
getent shadow "username"
```

Copy the line again

```
vipw -s
```

Paste the line into it. Then use

```
passwd "username"
```

to set the password itself again. 'getent' won't give you the encrypted
LDAP password.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but changes like that are handled in /etc/nsswitch.conf. Look for the users section in that file, that should tell you if it's local (files) or ldap.